# Process() fails macOS swift

Tags: python, swift, macos, process

I am trying to run python script from my macOS app. So I added the following code:

```
public class func run(name: String, arguments: [String] = [], environment: [String: String] = [:]) -> ScriptResponse {
    
    let result = self.runResolved(path: "/usr/bin/which", arguments: ["python"], environment: environment)
    return result
}

private class func runResolved(path: String, arguments: [String], environment: [String: String]) -> ScriptResponse {
    
    let outputPipe = Pipe()
    let errorPipe = Pipe()
    
    let outputFile = outputPipe.fileHandleForReading
    let errorFile = errorPipe.fileHandleForReading
    
    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = path
    task.arguments = arguments
    
    var env = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment

    environment.enumerated().forEach { entry in
        env[entry.element.key] = entry.element.value
    }

    task.environment = env
    task.standardOutput = outputPipe
    task.standardError = errorPipe
    
    task.launch()
    task.waitUntilExit()
    
    let terminationStatus = Int(task.terminationStatus)
    let output = self.stringFromFileAndClose(file: outputFile)
    let error = self.stringFromFileAndClose(file: errorFile)
    
    return (terminationStatus, output, error)
}
```

However, I think the code is correct, yet it always produces the following result:

`(terminationStatus: 1, standardOutput: "", standardError: "")`

My python location after I type `/usr/bin/which python`:

`/Users/me/.pyenv/shims/python`

Anyone knows and can help me to understand why the Process() fails?

Comment: Is your app sandboxed? That prohibits spawning subprocesses like this

Comment: No, it's not sandboxed

Comment: I can hard code `/Users/me/.pyenv/shims/python` and it works, but whenever I call `/usr/bin/which python` it fails.

Comment: I suspect it has to do with pyenv being part of your `$PATH` (probably set in `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.zshrc`, etc.)